# Modifying a query to work with multiple users using SEDE

Tags: t-sql, dataexplorer, sede

I am having a hard time getting my query to do what I want it to do...

If I run it for one UserId: 2140173 it seems to be working fine

```
Select UserId, 
(Select Count(VoteTypeId) From SuggestedEditVotes where UserId = 2140173) as 'Total',
(Select Count(VoteTypeId) From SuggestedEditVotes where UserId = 2140173 and VoteTypeId = 2) As 'Accepted',
(Select Count(VoteTypeId) From SuggestedEditVotes where UserId = 2140173 and VoteTypeId = 3) As 'Rejected'

from SuggestedEditVotes

    inner join Users on SuggestedEditVotes.UserId = Users.Id

where Users.Reputation > 2000 and UserId = 2140173

group by UserId

having Count(VoteTypeId) > 0
```

it returns

```
UserId    Total    Accepted    Rejected
2140173    2230        1145        1085
```

But when I am trying to modify it slightly and run it for all users with more than 2000 reputation it does not give me the correct results :/

I am stuck with the sub Select statements as I am not sure what to put in their `where` clause..

This is what I have tried but it returns the totals and I want it to be a count for each user Id

```
Select UserId, 
(Select Count(VoteTypeId) From SuggestedEditVotes) as 'Total',
(Select Count(VoteTypeId) From SuggestedEditVotes where VoteTypeId = 2) As 'Accepted',
(Select Count(VoteTypeId) From SuggestedEditVotes where VoteTypeId = 3) As 'Rejected'

from SuggestedEditVotes

    inner join Users on SuggestedEditVotes.UserId = Users.Id

where Users.Reputation > 2000

group by UserId

having Count(VoteTypeId) > 0
```

Can anyone help?

NOTE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT UserId,
 COUNT(VoteTypeId) AS 'Total',
 COUNT(
 CASE
   WHEN VoteTypeId = 2
   THEN VoteTypeId
   ELSE NULL
 END) AS 'Accepted',
 COUNT(
 CASE
   WHEN VoteTypeId = 3
   THEN VoteTypeId
   ELSE NULL
 END) AS 'Rejected'
FROM SuggestedEditVotes
INNER JOIN Users
ON SuggestedEditVotes.UserId = Users.Id
WHERE Users.Reputation       > 2000
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(VoteTypeId) > 0
```